# LINQ performance Count vs Where and Count

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Group
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
List<Group> _groups = new List<Group>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    var group = new Group();

    group.Name = i + "asdasdasd";
    _groups.Add(group);
}

Stopwatch _stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();

_stopwatch2.Start();
foreach (var group in _groups)
{
    var count = _groups.Count(x => x.Name == group.Name);
}
_stopwatch2.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(_stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

_stopwatch.Start();
foreach (var group in _groups)
{
    var count = _groups.Where(x => x.Name == group.Name).Count();
}
_stopwatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Result: First: 2863, Second 2185

Can someone explain me why first approach is slower than second? Second should return enumerator and invoke count on it and first just invoke count. First approach should be a little faster.

EDIT: I removed counter lists to prevent using GC and changed order to check if ordering has meaning. Results are almost the same.

EDIT2: This performance problem is not related only with Count. It's related with First(),FirstOrDefault(), Any(), etc.. Where + Method is always faster than Method.

Comment: Your measuring is not accurate — you are not doing warm up

Comment: How have you defined counters and counters2 ? I have seen declaring them with initial sizes (i.e. List<int> counter = new List<int>(500); really affects performance. Have you possibly declared them differently ? Secondly would it be useful to do a GC.Collect in between your two loops - possibly the GC is kicking in and distorting your results (really a very long shot that one ..)

Comment: Could you please provide the whole sample including collection declarations, initialization, etc. Guessing what you use is not the most productive way to help you :)

Comment: What type is `counters`? My guess would be `List<bool>` but that wouldn't make much sense. Also i think `Skip(1).Any()` would be faster.

Comment: Ok, following my earlier comment, I've copied your code and concur with your results. I get the same.

Comment: I edited post, no counters list

Comment: My only hunch is that Count() itself is "relatively" expensive, and on the first loop only gets called a fraction of the time, but on the second gets called more often. Out to get my trusty copy of Reflector.

Comment: OK, I edited this a bit on my machine by adding a warmup run, GC.Collect with finalization prior to measured runs. Running in Release build without VS this gives me 2.8 secs for Count and 2.66 for Where+Count. Now we need to explain this...

Comment: Yeah, the iteration within Count() and Where() is coded subtly different. Count() just uses a standard GetEnumerator to iterate but Where() uses an internal class called WhereEnumerableIterator. I cant work out what the perf difference would be, but the fact is that they are different under the hood and I guess the Where() one is more performant ... Glad to see if anyone has the time to spell out exactly why this might be though.

Comment: Thanks to the long running time warmup effects should not come into play. Well done. Did you run this in Release mode without debugger attached?

Comment: Debug/Release doesn't matter. Without debugger.

Comment: @Zbigniew just to make sure: This was run in Release mode, right? Try swapping the two tests. Does that change the outcome?

Comment: I think it's the order of things, like set based vs RBAR in SQL. You're filtering then getting the list size which is faster than filtering each row and incrementing. But this is just a hypothesis.

Comment: @usr Debug mode and release mode doesn't matter. Where + Method is faster than Method.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The crucial thing is in the implementation of `Where()` where it casts the `IEnumerable` to a `List<T>` if it can. Note the cast where `WhereListIterator` is constructed (this is from .Net source code obtained via reflection):

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source is List<TSource>) return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
    return new WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
}
```

I have verified this by copying (and simplifying where possible) the .Net implementations.

Crucially, I implemented two versions of `Count()` - one called `TestCount()` where I use `IEnumerable<T>`, and one called `TestListCount()` where I cast the enumerable to `List<T>` before counting the items.

This gives the same speedup as we see for the `Where()` operator which (as shown above) also casts to `List<T>` where it can.

(This should be tried with a release build without a debugger attached.)

This demonstrates that it is faster to use `foreach` to iterate over a `List<T>` compared to the same sequence represented via a `IEnumerable<T>`.

Firstly, here's the complete test code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Group
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int dummy = 0;
            List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                var group = new Group();

                group.Name = i + "asdasdasd";
                groups.Add(group);
            }

            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            for (int outer = 0; outer < 4; ++outer)
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();

                foreach (var group in groups)
                    dummy += TestWhere(groups, x => x.Name == group.Name).Count();

                Console.WriteLine("Using TestWhere(): " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                stopwatch.Restart();

                foreach (var group in groups)
                    dummy += TestCount(groups, x => x.Name == group.Name);

                Console.WriteLine("Using TestCount(): " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

                stopwatch.Restart();

                foreach (var group in groups)
                    dummy += TestListCount(groups, x => x.Name == group.Name);

                Console.WriteLine("Using TestListCount(): " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Total = " + dummy);
        }

        public static int TestCount<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (TSource element in source)
            {
                if (predicate(element)) 
                    count++;
            }

            return count;
        }

        public static int TestListCount<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            return testListCount((List<TSource>) source, predicate);
        }

        private static int testListCount<TSource>(List<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (TSource element in source)
            {
                if (predicate(element))
                    count++;
            }

            return count;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TSource> TestWhere<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            return new WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
        }
    }

    class WhereListIterator<TSource>: Iterator<TSource>
    {
        readonly Func<TSource, bool> predicate;
        List<TSource>.Enumerator enumerator;

        public WhereListIterator(List<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            this.predicate = predicate;
            this.enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public override bool MoveNext()
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                TSource item = enumerator.Current;
                if (predicate(item))
                {
                    current = item;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            Dispose();

            return false;
        }
    }

    abstract class Iterator<TSource>: IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerator<TSource>
    {
        internal TSource current;

        public TSource Current
        {
            get
            {
                return current;
            }
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            current = default(TSource);
        }

        public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public abstract bool MoveNext();

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        void IEnumerator.Reset()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's the IL generated for the two crucial methods, `TestCount():` and `testListCount()`. Remember that the only difference between these is that `TestCount()` is using the `IEnumerable<T>` and `testListCount()` is using the same enumerable, but cast to its underlying `List<T>` type:

```
TestCount():

.method public hidebysig static int32 TestCount<TSource>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!TSource> source, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!TSource, bool> predicate) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 count,
        [1] !!TSource element,
        [2] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!!TSource> CS$5$0000)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0001: stloc.0 
    L_0002: ldarg.0 
    L_0003: callvirt instance class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!0> [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!TSource>::GetEnumerator()
    L_0008: stloc.2 
    L_0009: br L_0025
    L_000e: ldloc.2 
    L_000f: callvirt instance !0 [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!!TSource>::get_Current()
    L_0014: stloc.1 
    L_0015: ldarg.1 
    L_0016: ldloc.1 
    L_0017: callvirt instance !1 [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!TSource, bool>::Invoke(!0)
    L_001c: brfalse L_0025
    L_0021: ldloc.0 
    L_0022: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0023: add.ovf 
    L_0024: stloc.0 
    L_0025: ldloc.2 
    L_0026: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
    L_002b: brtrue.s L_000e
    L_002d: leave L_003f
    L_0032: ldloc.2 
    L_0033: brfalse L_003e
    L_0038: ldloc.2 
    L_0039: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    L_003e: endfinally 
    L_003f: ldloc.0 
    L_0040: ret 
    .try L_0009 to L_0032 finally handler L_0032 to L_003f
}


testListCount():

.method private hidebysig static int32 testListCount<TSource>(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!TSource> source, class [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!TSource, bool> predicate) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 count,
        [1] !!TSource element,
        [2] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!!TSource> CS$5$0000)
    L_0000: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0001: stloc.0 
    L_0002: ldarg.0 
    L_0003: callvirt instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!0> [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<!!TSource>::GetEnumerator()
    L_0008: stloc.2 
    L_0009: br L_0026
    L_000e: ldloca.s CS$5$0000
    L_0010: call instance !0 [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!!TSource>::get_Current()
    L_0015: stloc.1 
    L_0016: ldarg.1 
    L_0017: ldloc.1 
    L_0018: callvirt instance !1 [mscorlib]System.Func`2<!!TSource, bool>::Invoke(!0)
    L_001d: brfalse L_0026
    L_0022: ldloc.0 
    L_0023: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0024: add.ovf 
    L_0025: stloc.0 
    L_0026: ldloca.s CS$5$0000
    L_0028: call instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!!TSource>::MoveNext()
    L_002d: brtrue.s L_000e
    L_002f: leave L_0042
    L_0034: ldloca.s CS$5$0000
    L_0036: constrained [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!!TSource>
    L_003c: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    L_0041: endfinally 
    L_0042: ldloc.0 
    L_0043: ret 
    .try L_0009 to L_0034 finally handler L_0034 to L_0042
}
```

I think that the important lines here is where it calls `IEnumerator::GetCurrent()` and `IEnumerator::MoveNext()`.

In the first case it is:

```
callvirt instance !0 [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator`1<!!TSource>::get_Current()
callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerator::MoveNext()
```

And in the second case it is:

```
call instance !0 [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!!TSource>::get_Current()
call instance bool [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!!TSource>::MoveNext()
```

Importantly, in the second case a non-virtual call is being made - which can be significantly faster than a virtual call if it is in a loop (which it is, of course).

Comment: Brilliant! Surely `call` vs `callvirt` is the real reason. The `Where` iterator avoids indirect virtual table call, but calls iterator methods directly. Thanks for this investigation.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me that the difference is in how the Linq extensions are coded.  I suspect `Where` is using optimizations in the `List<>` class to speed up the operations, but `Count` just iterates through an `IEnumerable<>`.

If you do the same process, but with an `IEnumerable`, both methods are close, with `Where` being slightly slower.

```
List<Group> _groups = new List<Group>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    var group = new Group();

    group.Name = i + "asdasdasd";
    _groups.Add(group);
}

IEnumerable<Group> _groupsEnumerable = from g in _groups select g;

Stopwatch _stopwatch2 = new Stopwatch();

_stopwatch2.Start();
foreach (var group in _groups)
{
    var count = _groupsEnumerable.Count(x => x.Name == group.Name);
}
_stopwatch2.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(_stopwatch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

_stopwatch.Start();
foreach (var group in _groups)
{
    var count = _groupsEnumerable.Where(x => x.Name == group.Name).Count();
}
_stopwatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine(_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Where extension method.  Notice the `if (source is List<TSource>)` case:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    }
    if (source is Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>)
    {
        return ((Enumerable.Iterator<TSource>)source).Where(predicate);
    }
    if (source is TSource[])
    {
        return new Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator<TSource>((TSource[])source, predicate);
    }
    if (source is List<TSource>)
    {
        return new Enumerable.WhereListIterator<TSource>((List<TSource>)source, predicate);
    }
    return new Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator<TSource>(source, predicate);
}
```

Count method.  Just iterates through the IEnumerable:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    }
    int num = 0;
    checked
    {
        foreach (TSource current in source)
        {
            if (predicate(current))
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good find! According to Reflector, `Where` has a special case for `List<T>`. `Where` gets 99% of the running time. `Count` is only relevant for one item in this test. Make the predicate `x => true` to make the `Count` version faster again.

Comment: This does not explain what 'optimizations' are used. As far as I can tell, it still has to iterate the list in both cases. Can you explain which optimization makes the difference?

Comment: @usr I tried looking at the difference between `WhereListIterator` and `WhereEnumerableIterator` and see no real difference. Could you point to the place where you found that out?

Comment: But `Count` has no special version for a `WhereListIterator` and the only difference between `Count` without a predicate and the one with a predicate parameter is that the version without a predicate directly uses the underlying `GetEnumerator` while the `Count` with a predicate uses a foreach.

Comment: The code added to the post shows no real evidence of the difference between that two cases.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov.  You're right, that edit wasn't necessarily in response to Pavel Gatilov.  Surely the list has to be the difference.

Comment: Calls to List are hard-coded. No virtual calls. Inlineable. Why else would the special case have been added? It was added for performance reasons.

Comment: I wish Microsoft would define an `IEnhancedEnumerator<T>` type inherited from `IEnumerator<T>` and have the enumerators of types like `List<T>` implement it.  Such a feature would make it possible to operate efficiently on collections that are wrapped by methods like `Skip()` or `Concat()`, or wrapped in types like `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.  As it is, there's almost no way to wrap or encapsulate a collection without blocking all means of access other than item-by-item sequential iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Matthew Watson's answer:

The reason iterating over a `List<T>` generates `call` instructions rather than `callvirt`, as used for `IEnumerable<T>`, is that the C# `foreach` statement is duck-typed.

The C# Language Specification, section 8.8.4, says that the compiler 'determines whether the type X has an appropriate GetEnumerator method'. This is used in preference to an enumerable interface. Therefore the `foreach` statement here uses the overload of `List<T>.GetEnumerator` which returns a `List<T>.Enumerator` rather than the version that returns `IEnumerable<T>` or just `IEnumerable`.

The compiler also checks that the type returned by `GetEnumerator` has a `Current` property and a `MoveNext` method that takes no arguments. For `List<T>.Enumerator`, these methods are *not* marked `virtual`, so the compiler can compile a direct call. In contrast, in `IEnumerator<T>` they *are* `virtual` so the compiler must generate a `callvirt` instruction. The extra overhead of calling through the virtual function table explains the difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

.Where() uses special "**WhereListIterator**" to iterate over elements, Count() does not, as indicated by Wyatt Earp. The interesting thing is that the iterator is marked as "ngenable":

```
 [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
 public WhereListIterator(List<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
 {
   this.source = source;
   this.predicate = predicate;
 }
```

This would probably mean that the "iterator" part runs as a "unmanaged code", while the Count() runs as a managed code. I don't know if that makes sense / how to prove it, but that's my 0.2cents.

Also, if you rewrite the Count() to take care of List carefully,

you can make it the same / even faster:

```
public static class TestExt{
   public static int CountFaster<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
       if (source == null) throw new Exception();
       if (predicate == null) throw new Exception();

       if(source is List<TSource>)
       {
                int finalCount=0;
                var list = (List<TSource>)source;
                var count = list.Count;
                for(var j = 0; j < count; j++){
                    if(predicate(list[j])) 
                        finalCount++;
                }
                return finalCount;
       }


       return source.Count(predicate);
   }
```

}

On my tests; after I've started using CountFaster(), the one who is called LATER wins(because of cold-startup).

Comment: I don't think this makes sense, ultimately, all code runs as unmanaged code.

Comment: I've made a test application which has no attributes, but which uses the .Net implementation, and the more complex implementation is still faster!

Comment: Well it would matter in the sense that if both codes are optimal, then the ngen one would win in cold-startup. Ps @MatthewWatson; I added the  implementation, on my machine the two implementations are the same now.

Answer (score 0):

According to @Matthew Watson post I checked some behaviour. In my example "Where" always returned empty collection so Count was not even invoked on interface IEnumerable (which is significantly slower than enumerating on List elements). Instead of adding all groups with different name I added all items with the same name. Then Count is faster than Count + Method. This is because in Count approach we enumerate on interface IEnumerable over all items. In Method + Count approach if all items are identical, "Where" returns whole collection (casted to IEnumerable interface) and it invokes Count(), so Where invoke is redundant or I can say - it's slowing things down.

All in all, specific situation in this example led me to conclusions that Method + Where is always faster but it is not true. If "Where" returns collection which is not much smaller than the original collection "Method + Where approach" will be slower.

Answer (score -3):

Sarge Borsch gave the proper answer in the comments but without further explanations.

The problems lies with the fact that the bytecode must be compiled to x86 by the JIT compiler on the first run. As a result your measure incorporates both what you wanted to test and the compilation time. And since most of the things used by the second test will have been compiled during the first test (the list enumerator, the Name property getter, etc), the first one is more impacted by the compilation.

The solution is to do a "warm-up": you run your code once without doing measures, usually with just one iteration, simply to have it compiled. Then you start the stopwatch and run it again for real, with as many iterations as needed to get a long enough duration (one second for example).

Comment: This can't be right - I tested by moving all initialisations outside an inner loop, and looped the whole test several times with the same results.

Comment: JIT time does not explain 700ms difference. Good benchmarks run for a long time so that no one-time effects can come into play. This is a good benchmark.

Comment: I tested with another ordering. It doesn't matter. Where + Method is always faster.

Comment: I tested that too, like @Zbigniew and came to the same result.