# Lambda where condition in Join statement

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have to filter `Employee` based on their `department`.  I'm able to do the same with LINQ.

`Linq` and `lambda` compile to get same result. The compiler changes the query expression into the equivalent `Lambda expression` before compiling it, so the generated IL is exactly the same.[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914611/comparision-linq-vs-lambda-expression)

```
var deptCollection = new List<Dept>();
var employeeCollection = new List<Employee>();

employeeCollection.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Eldho" });

deptCollection.Add(new Dept { DepetarmentName = "a", EmployeeId = 3 });
deptCollection.Add(new Dept { DepetarmentName = "a", EmployeeId = 1 });

var empinadept = (from e in employeeCollection
                  from dep in deptCollection
                  where e.Id == dep.EmployeeId
                  && dep.DepetarmentName == "a"
                  select e)
                 .ToList();
```

> I can't able to add `.Where` Clause in this lambda

```
var empindeptLamda = employeeCollection
                     .Join(deptCollection,
                     emp => emp.Id, dep => dep.EmployeeId,
                     (em, dep) => em.Id == dep.EmployeeId
                      && dep.DepetarmentName == "a")
                     .ToList();

class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Dept
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string DepetarmentName { get; set; }
}
```

**Q1. What is the equivalent lambda statement for the above linq ?** (How to add where clause as in linq in method-syntax

Comment: Use whichever format is more readable...

Comment: [Is it Linq or Lambda?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391370/is-it-linq-or-lambda) This post is pretty good

Comment: Basically both are Linq, however the one is a query-syntax and the other is the method-syntax.

Comment: @AustinFrench how should i use where condition with `join`

Comment: You add it after the `.Join` or do a join with [multiple conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664727/linq-join-with-multiple-conditions-in-on-clause)

Comment: FYI.  The terms are query syntax and method syntax.  Both are Linq and lambdas are the anonymous delegate that you tend to use in method syntax.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand joins and you have written two very confusing queries. The 1st has a double `from`, which translates into a `SelectMany`. But then you filter the results by comparing Id's **which is what join does**, so this query should have been a join. In your 2nd query `(em, dep) => em.Id == dep.EmployeeId && dep.DepetarmentName == "a")` is a **selector**. It **selects** a boolean value. (this query produces an `IEnumerable<bool>`, all with the value `true`) The filtering is done by the previous 2 lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent for this:

```
var empinadept = (from e in employeeCollection
              from dep in deptCollection
              where e.Id == dep.EmployeeId
              && dep.DepetarmentName == "a"
              select e)
             .ToList();
```

Is this:

```
var result = employeeCollection.Join(deptCollection,
        e => e.Id,
        dep => dep.EmployeeId,
        (e,dep) => new { e, dep })
    .Where(item => item.dep.DepetarmentName == "a")
    .Select(item => item.e)
    .ToList();
```

A better option will be to:

```
var result = employeeCollection.Join(
            deptCollection.Where(dep => dep.DepetarmentName == "a"),
            e => e.Id,
            dep => dep.EmployeeId,
            (e,dep) => e)
       .ToList();
```

Closest to the query-syntax (but I would say that is less nice *opinion based*) is:

```
var result = employeeCollection.Join(
        deptCollection,
        e => new { e.Id, "a" },
        dep => new { dep.EmployeeId, dep.DepartmentName },
        (e,dep) => e).ToList();
```

Comment: This works for me, when i benchmarked it, Linq is faster than lamda. The figures are 001940 ms for linq and 0058248 for lamda.

Comment: @Eldho - I wouldn't rush to say it is faster (might be true but I don't know enough) - I'd check the sql that is being generated and check. Also compare for different Databases

Comment: This are in memory objects, i have this in a List

Comment: ah ok :) also compare what happens when you play with first the Where and then the join and so on, and ToList too, but again could be that you are correct

Comment: @Eldho - For performance you can start with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576999/linq-lambda-vs-query-syntax-performance)

Comment: Sure, thank you , Do we have any option to write the same with lamda, My project so far only contains lamda no linq, So to stay consistent i should use lamda without lossing performance. i have 2k list to compare with.

Comment: I think using objects like HashSets will be more beneficial for the performance that if it is query or method syntaxs. I'd go with what is more readable - sometimes it is methods, sometimes it is the query - and this is already personal preference too

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. What is the equivalent lamda statement for the above linq ?

```
var empindeptLamda = employeeCollection
    .Join(deptCollection, emp => emp.Id, dep => dep.EmployeeId, (e, dep) => new { e, dep })
    .Where(x => x.dep.DepetarmentName == "a")
    .Select(x => x.e)
    .ToList();
```

> Q2. When should i choose <del>LINQ vs Lamda</del> method syntax or query syntax ?

This is really your personal preference. Since they are compiled into the same IL, so the performance is the same. However, there is some situation where query syntax is preferred, such as having multiple join clause. And other time where the method syntax shines, like adding your own extensions method, or debugging the intermediate result between each method.

Comment: you don't need the `Id == EmployeeId` in the `Where` - you already did it in the `Join`

Comment: @GiladGreen Yea, you are right, it was implied.