# Count(x => ...) vs Where(x => ...).Count()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is there any difference between these two LINQ-to-Entities queries:

```
context.Table.Count(x => ...)
```

and

```
context.Table.Where(x => ...).Count()
```

in terms of performance and generated SQL?

I tried to look generated SQL myself, but I only know how to get the SQL from `IQueryable`, but `Count` returns the value directly.

Comment: The **b**est way to know it is to **t**est it... IMO, there seems to be (only) a little difference between those two though..

Comment: Yes, but how? I don't know how to see the generated SQL.

Comment: I mean, by timing it... not necessary by looking at the generated SQL. Give difficult cases for both (like querying 1000000 times or so...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787555/linq-performance-count-vs-where-and-count

Comment: [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @monstertjie_za, it is LINQ to Objects, and my case is LINQ to Entities. The results may differ highly because LINQ to Entities is translated to SQL.

Comment: @AlekseyShubin I understand, just thought I would put it out there for you to give a read.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thanks! Will try to see the query using this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to see the SQL (thanks to @dasblinkenlight), the answer is - no, both LINQ queries generate exactly the same SQL query, at least for a simple query without a grouping:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE <condition>
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: there may be a little difference since in the second solution there is second function call (first the call to the where function and then a Count(). I don't think this makes sooo much difference when use rarely

Comment: Yes, but I think the additional function call time is negligible compared to overall database connection and SQL execution time.

Comment: as i said in my post :D